# Creating a pivot table with no agg function while using a group by?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Right now I have a table that looks like this called "student_proficiencies":

[image]

The `student_application_id` are not unique, meaning they could be duplicated depending on how the student answers (As you can see for multiple entries of 23541)

I want to create a table such as this:
[image]

I want to group by `student_application_id` so that every id is unique in the new table, but the columns become the skills, and the values within those columns are the strengths depending on if that `student_application_id` answered that particular skill ("Python", "Excel" etc...)

How would I go about writing a SQL query here? I know this would be a PIVOT problem, but I'm not sure how an AGG function would play into this.

```
SELECT * from student_proficiences
GROUP BY student_application_id....
PIVOT (...?)
```

Thanks

EDIT: I'm using SQL in BigQuery

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the list of proficiencies, you can use:

```
select student_application_id,
       max(case when skill = 'statistics' then strength end) as statistics,
       max(case when skill = 'Excel' then strength end) as excel,
       . . . 
from t
group by student_application_id;
```